# Why does sending ' symbol to mariadb cause it to show '> instead of >

Tags: sql, mariadb, raspbian

Accidentally sent the ' symbol when logged into MarisDB sql server. Now the > symbol is showing as ->. When I enter ' again it changes to '>. When in either of these states I cannot run sql commmands. What is happening here?

running Raspbian and mariadb. Ran 'sudo mysql -u root -p' then entered password to connect. Hit ' followed by enter and now sql commands don't work. Only solution I found is Ctrl+c which aborts. Here's example from terminal:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> ';
    '> 
    '> Ctrl-C -- exit!
Aborted
```

First line causes the problem, second line shows new > with ' before it, third line I hit Ctrl+c, fourth line is the response which leads back to normal terminal disconnected from MariaDB.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo mysql -u root -p
Enter password:

MariaDB [(none)]> ';
    '> Ctrl-C -- exit!
Aborted
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

Comment: That's the command line interpreter of MariaDB. It thinks you are trying to type a multi-line literal.

Comment: The client SQL interpreter believes you intended to start a literal string, which are single quoted `'string value'`, and is prompting you to close the string with a `'` because it was left open over a newline.

Comment: It will do the same thing if you start a parenthetical `(` and don't close it before hitting enter. If you start a string literal or parenthetical or similar you have to eventually close it. It's even nice enough to tell you what you need to close up yet.